# jQuery select multiple items with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple elements (`<td>`) with different id's : box1, box2...boxN. and I want to select some in order to change their color, the thing is that I need to use a variable `board[][]` which returns a value that determine what item will be affected, so I tried to use concatenation :

```
$('#box'+board[i][0],'#box'+board[i][1],'#box'+board[i][2]).css(...)
```

It works fine with a single item, but adding more than one didn't work, so I tried using variables:

```
var $box1=$("#box"+board[i][0])
var $box2=$("#box"+board[i][1])
var $box3=$("#box"+board[i][2])
$($box1,$box2,$box3).css(...)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `$box1.add($box2).add($box3)` better still, use a common class on all the elements: `$('.box')`

Comment: isnt `( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )` instead`("selector1"," selector2", "selectorN")` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it's not always 1 2 3, thats why I'm using board variable

Comment: @Nico, adding "" causes an error when using '' for concatenation.

Comment: @AdelSenhadji ok, but the point is you need to use `add()` to merge jQuery objects together.